# Retrofit 2 RequestBody Content Length Greater Than File Size

Tags: android, retrofit, kotlin

I have an Api which requires me to send up the size of a file in bytes before I then send up the actual file. When I call `file.length()` on the file to send up in the first Api call, it returns `1996`.

When I then package the file up into a `RequestBody` the `contentLength()` becomes `2556`. The server then rejects this, saying that these sizes must match.

Here is the code for creating the `RequestBody`.

```
val requestBody = RequestBody.create(
                        MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"),
                        avatarFile)
```

- What is being added in the `RequestBody` to increase its content length?
- Should I just send up the size of the `RequestBody` on the first call to get around this problem?

**EDIT**

Here is where I call the API the first time to send the size initially:

```
return authService.updateAvatar(
                    AvatarMetadataRequest(
                            size = avatarFile.length().toInt(),
                            crc = profileImageProvider.getFile()!!.checksum()!!.toInt()))
```

And then this is where I call it the second time when the file actually gets uploaded:

```
        val avatarFile = profileImageProvider.getFile()

        val requestBody = RequestBody.create(
                MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"),
                avatarFile)
        return authService.uploadAvatar(
                id.split("/").last(),
                MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("avatar",
                        profileImageProvider.getFileName(),
                        requestBody))
```

It turns out the `contentLength()` of the `requestBody` is correct. So the `Content-Length` must be being modified or increased when the `MultipartBody.Part.createFormData` is called.

Comment: `OkHttp`'s `RequestBody.contentLength()` just [forwards to file.length()](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/RequestBody.java#L113) under the hood, so I'm confused as to how this could happen.

Comment: If you could add some more code (e.g. the part where you call the API to send the file size), it might help.

Comment: @PixelElephant you are correct. The `ResponseBody` isn't the issue. It's adding it on elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a mistake on the part of the avatar upload API. The avatar is being uploaded as MultipartData and so will never equal the raw size of the file. This is because a multipart request will have additional data besides the file.

Here is an example multipart request:

```
--------------------------0b880724ca8aacd6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

test test test

--------------------------0b880724ca8aacd6--
```

As you can see, the content of the file is just `test test test`. Everything else is additional data added by the multipart request.

The raw size on disk is 15 bytes, while the Content-Length of the request is 202, due to all the extra data.

So the avatar upload API should not just be checking the Content-Length of the entire request, but rather extracting the specific part relating to the file and just checking the size of the data contained in that part.

If you have no control over the behaviour of the avatar upload API, then you can attempt to calculate the total Content-Length by figuring out the total size of the overhead added by the multipart request and adding that to your file size.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the detailed answer. Is there another way of sending a binary file with retrofit 2?