# How to get the size of FilePart in Spring Webflux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

Cannot figure out how to get actual size of file using FilePart in REST endpoint:

```java
@RestController
public class SomeController {

    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public Mono<Long> fileSize(Mono<FilePart> filePart) {
        
        //How to get size of FilePart?

        // I'm not plan to create a File saving content of FilePart. 
        // Maybe it's possible somehow calculate size of all bytes.

        return Mono.empty();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Below is the way I do file size and image resolution validation.

Controller:

```java
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public Mono<Void> upload(Mono<FilePart> file) {
    return file.flatMap(filepart -> fileService.upload(filepart));
}
```

Validation methods in service layer:

```java
private Mono<byte[]> validateFileSize(FilePart filePart) {
    var maxSize = 1024;
    return FilePartUtils.getByteArray(filePart)
            .filter(bytes -> bytes.length <= maxSize)
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(() -> new InvalidStateException(MAX_FILE_SIZE_REACHED, Map.of("size", maxSize))));
}

private Mono<Resolution> validateResolution(byte[] fileBytes) {
    // Use image.getWidth and image.getHeight to check resolution against you expectations
    return convertToImage(fileBytes).map(image -> validateResolution(image)); 
}

public Mono<BufferedImage> convertToImage(byte[] byteArray) {
    try {
        // but ImageIO.read is blocking method
        return Mono.just(ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return Mono.error(new InvalidStateException(UPLOAD_FILE_ABORTED, Map.of()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Viktor, I know it's really late and probably you figured this out yourselves. But still if my answer helped answering your question, please accept and close this topic

Comment: Hey @AbhinabaChakraborty, your answer is also correct, and can be used for file size validation. I still convert FilePart to byte array to validate file size and then to BufferedImage to validate image resolution in my concrete case.

Comment: @ViktorV. could you please share that part of code where you check file size and then cast to BufferedImage to validate image resolution? because that is actually what i need right now, and i cannot figure it out the way to do it

Comment: @Vovabackend_dev Added into UPDATED section above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**When you upload a file as multipart form data, a request header called "Content-Length" gets automatically created, which is calculated when request is sent**.

However note that, **the multipart content-length is slightly greater than the file size** due to some metadata created like the file name , boundary and all. And there is **no way** you can estimate the length of this metadata. Explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45241994/retrofit-2-requestbody-content-length-greater-than-file-size).

Thus you can get the size (slightly increased) in this way:

```
@RestController
public class SomeController {

    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public Mono<Long> fileSize(Mono<FilePart> filePart, @RequestHeader("Content-Length") long contentLength) {
        System.out.println("Content length is:" + contentLength + "bytes");
        return Mono.empty();
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it safe to rely on the content-length header? For example, is this possible that malcious user can set this header to e.g. 100kb while the file is much bigger?

Answer (score 3):

You can get access to the `Flux<DataBuffer>` in filepart with `filePart.content()`. Use this.

```
filePart.content() // for one file, is a Flux with one element
    .map(dataBuffer -> {
         byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()]; // <---- here you count the bytes you have. 
         dataBuffer.read(bytes);
         DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
         String content = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
         if (log.isTraceEnabled()) log.trace("File name: {}, content: {}", filePart.filename(),
             content.length() > CONTENT_LENGTH_LIMIT ? content.substring(0, CONTENT_LENGTH_LIMIT) + "..." : content);
         return content;
    })
```

Comment: sure but you read the whole file into memory this way, right? eg. it's not the best for large files

Comment: No, it is not; I mean, I don't expect a tooooo large uploaded file like 2G.. but if we have a solution to read it into chunks, why not? Please suggest. Here I read it and I release it, leaving only the size. If not for logging, even `content` can be left out.

Answer (score -3):

I also could not figure out how to get the file size without first saving it to a File, or reducing it to a InputStream or something like that.

What I ended up doing was to add a custom header to the request. You can then read your header in your controller:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public Mono<Long> fileSize(Mono<FilePart> filePart, @RequestHeader("File-Size") Long fileSize) {
```

If you change the type of the new parameter to `Map<String, String>`, or `MultiValueMap<String, String>`, or `HttpHeaders` you will get all headers, not only your custom one.

If you can't change the client's request headers, and you don't need the file size to be absolutely precise, you could use the default header `Content-Length`, which is already sent anyway, but this will be off by a few bytes.